# Python requests writes the name of the file instead of contents to web page

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a function that tries to write a web page into conflunece. Instead of posting the contents of a file, it writes the name of the file to the page.

I am using the python requests module to write to the web page.

On the web page I see this:

```
../output_files/aws_instance_list/html/aws-master-list-06-05-2019.html
```

As the only contents of the page.

This is the code that I'm using to write to the page:

```
htmlfile = '../output_files/aws_instance_list/html/aws-master-list-06-05-2019.html'
pageid = 138317098
auth = ('username','password')
write_data(auth, htmlfile, pageid, 'AWS EC2 Instance List')
def write_data(auth, htmlfile, pageid, title = None):
    info = get_page_info(auth, pageid)
    ver = int(info['version']['number']) + 1
    ancestors = get_page_ancestors(auth, pageid)
    anc = ancestors[-1]
    del anc['_links']
    del anc['_expandable']
    del anc['extensions']
    if title is not None:
        info['title'] = title
    data = {
        'id' : str(pageid),
        'type' : 'page',
        'title' : info['title'],
        'version' : {'number' : ver},
        'ancestors' : [anc],
        'body'  : {
        'storage' :
        {
            'representation' : 'storage',
            'value' : str(htmlfile),
         }
      }
    }
    data = json.dumps(data)
    url = '{base}/{pageid}'.format(base = BASE_URL, pageid = pageid)
    r = requests.put(
        url,
        data = data,
        auth = auth,
        headers = { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' }
    )
    r.raise_for_status()
    print("Wrote '%s' version %d" % (info['title'], ver))
    print("URL: %s%d" % (VIEW_URL, pageid))
```

I've looked at the contents of the 'htmlfile' and can see that it contains valid HTML.

How can I write the contents of the file to the page instead of the name of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the contents of the file.

```
'value' : open(htmlfile).read(),
```

Comment: I got an error when I tried that: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 417, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 383, in main
    write_data(auth, htmlfile, pageid, 'AWS EC2 Instance List')
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 302, in write_data
    r.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\tdunphy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)`

Comment: `requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://wiki.us.cworld.company.com/rest/api/content/138317098`

Comment: When I use `'value' : str(htmlfile)` it writes to the page, but it writes the wrong thing. It writes the name of the file instead of the contents of the html file. Thx

Comment: Problem was actually my HTML. And I did need an open statement. So I accepted your answer. The HTML was formed in another function that I didn't post, tho I'm sure I should have. Thanks for the help! It's working now.